# Understanding the Jacobian criterion for smoothness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm having trouble understanding the first condition of the Jacobian criterion for smoothness:

**Theorem:** (Jacobian criterion)

Given the following commutative diagram of schemes,

$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}   
Z & \xrightarrow{i} & \mathbb{A}_R^n \\\
&{f}\searrow  &  \downarrow{j} \\\  
&& \operatorname{Spec}R
\end{array}  $

where $i$ is a closed immersion which is locally of finite presentation, then for any $z\in Z$, $f$ is smooth at $z$ if and only if $Z=V(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$ locally around $z$, with $f_1,\ldots,f_r\in R[X_1,\ldots,X_r]$, and the rank of the Jacobi matrix $\mathcal{J}(z)=\left(\frac{\partial f_i(z)}{\partial X_j}\right)$ is $r$.

---

Why is $Z=V(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$ stated explicitly as a condition? Doesn't this already follow from the fact that $i$ is a closed immersion?

Comment: Yes, but the point is that it needs to be embeddable as a closed subscheme of a particular form--you can't state the conditions without specifying the fucntions which cut $Z$ out.

Comment: @AlexYoucis That is true, thanks!